# Java Multi-Dimensional Array: Memory Address and Traversal Speed

Tags: java, arrays, memory

I understand that when dealing with a 2-Dimensional Array in Java the order in which you access array elements in a loop can affect the time it takes to traverse the array:

```
int size = 500;
int[][] array = new int[size][size];

// Slower
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        array[j][i] = 1;
    }
}

// Faster
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        array[i][j] = 1;
    }
}
```

This makes sense to me because it requires less jumping around the memory and instead can just step to the subsequent address.

When doing the same with a 3-Dimensional Array, I was a little more confused with the results:

```
Time:  12356332 nanoseconds. ([i][j][k])
Time:  18278948 nanoseconds. ([i][k][j])
Time:  13985288 nanoseconds. ([j][i][k])
Time: 126192723 nanoseconds. ([j][k][i])
Time:  39441820 nanoseconds. ([k][i][j])
Time: 156352618 nanoseconds. ([k][j][i])
```

The results for `[i][j][k]` and `[j][i][k]` were interchangeable in most runs of the code. Why is this?

Additionally could you explain how multi-dimensional arrays are stored in Java?

given the array `int[][][] array = new int[2][2][2]` would the memory addresses look like this (*My understanding is that there may be additional data for other variables in between each block, but I have ommitted these cases as they are not relevant*):
[image: Multi-Dimensional Array Memory Addresses]
*(Sorry if the image is confusing, I only had paint to work with and tried to express the layout the best I could. so `array[0][0][0] //[i][j][k]` would be in the address `06`)*

Comment: How were you measuring this?  Measuring performance of these things in Java accurately (even accurately enough for "A is better than B") is _really, really hard_.

Comment: I used `System.nanoTime()` before and after each loop and subtracted the difference

Comment: Yeah, no, that's not going to get you accurate results.  Use JMH or Caliper if you want to get measurements that can actually tell you A is faster/slower/equal to B.

Comment: The technicla term for the java implementation of arrays is jagged arrays. See http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to consider is that java has, looking closely, *no multidimensional arrays* in the sense that its a single entity. Instead java only handles single dimension arrays, but the element type can be an array type itself and the language/compiler supports the same syntax as e.g. C does for multiple dimensions to shortcut addressing an element.

For example, `int[][] twoDim = new int[50][100];` actually creates 51 objects in memory; *one* array of type `int[][]` with space for 50 elements of type `int[]`, and the fills these 50 spaces with an array of type `int[100]` (making the remaining 50 objects). Each of these 51 objects are idependent, and they can be located *anywhere* in the heap. Actually they don't even need to be created in the same statement.

The follwing two methods give identical arrays as results, but the second should make clear whats *really* going on *under the hood*:

```
 public int[][] createArrayA(int n, int m) {
     return new int[n][m];
 }

 public int[][] createArrayB(int n, int m) {
     int[][] array = new int[n][];
     for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
         array[i] = new int[m];
     return array;
 }
```

Note that in createArrayB(), you could chose to initialize the n-dimension backwards (loop counting down instead of up) as well, leading to the same array:

```
 public int[][] createArrayC(int n, int m) {
     int[][] array = new int[n][];
     for (int i=n-1; i>=0; --i)
         array[i] = new int[m];
     return array;
 }
```

The memory layout of variants B an C will be different, because their allocation order is different. But don't assume their memory layout is a constant, the garbage collector may move them arround in the heap later.

*If* you are concerned about speed of access, the fastest way to iterate an array is always *leftmost dimension* goes to the *outermost loop*, *rightmost dimension* goes to the *innermost loop* (this is strictly built around the fact that the *individual dimensions* are located linearly in memory). And CPU's are faster with linear memory access than with random accesses (I'll not go into *why* that is here).

There are two micro-optimizations that *may* be considered when dealing with arrays.

First is the order of dimensions, when you are free to order the dimensions as you please, put the *smallest* leftmost and the largest *rightmost*:

```
int[][] slowArray = new int[10000][2];
int[][] fastArray = new int[2][10000];
```

The second also saves a lot of memory, because the slow variant consists of 10000 x int[2] = 10001 objects, while the fast variant consists of 2 x int[10000] = 3 objects.

The second is working with slices of an array dimension (its a form of code invariant movement):

```
long sum = 0;
int[][] fastArray = new int[2][10000];
for (int i=0; i<fastArray.length; ++i) {
    int[] subArray = fastArray[i];
    for (int j=0; j<subArray.length; ++j) {
        sum += subArray[j];
    }
}
```

Defining a local variable subArray eliminates the outer dimension completely from the inner loop (after all, i never changes in the inner loop, so why look up array index i each time you want to resolve j?). This kind of optimization *may* be performed automatically by the just in time compiler, but to the best of my knowledge its not *always* performed automatically. It doesn't matter for the occasional loop, but if the array walking makes a significant part of you processing time its an optimization to consider.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I do not quite comprehend the idea behind storing arrays of arrays of arrays... As far as bytecode is concerned, nothing prevents one from defining a n dimensional array the classic way using a single contiguous block of memory so as to get more predictable performance.

Comment: @edTarik The thing preventing you from defining a multi-dimensional array as a contigous block of memory is the java language specification itself, specifically in that each array *is (also) an Object*. Step (virtually or better yet in a debugger) through the createArrayB() example and take a look at the array contents throughout the method. Also you might want to check for the term "jagged array" (this feature is also a consequence of the array-of-arrays organization).

Comment: Well, you can easily get the equivalent of a 2D array using a single dimension array through the use of indexes. That's how C does it internally. As such, nothing in the JVM prevents adding syntactic sugar to Java programming language to handle 2D arrays along with the more traditional jagged array.

Comment: @edTarik I get your point, but that would still require a change at the language level; not just the VM level. There is a limit to what you can achieve with (pure) syntax sugar alone (take a look at my last code example with the code invariant movement for the *why*, it would be quite a fundamental addition). You can still emulate the classic C multi dimensional array by doing the indexing math yourself (with current java language elements), while actually storing the data in a single dimension array if you feel it gains you enough to be worth the effort.

Comment: I had a look at the code invariant code. I still do not quite understand what precludes using adding a Java syntactic construct to do exactly that: Using a one dimensional array and do the indexing math using an unchanged JVM.

Comment: @edTarik Thats probably because you're not familiar with the exact way things are handled in Java vs C. You could not obtain a reference to the inner slice (as the code invariant example does), there would be no place for the reference to point to. This is possible in C because there is neither a type nor a length implied by the pointer, but these are mandatory for java objects. Thats ignoring that arrays in Java are managed, that is you cannot accidentially address a non-existing index. While the concept may *look* simple to you, you're simply missing a lot of the implications.

Comment: "Thats probably because you're not familiar with the exact way things are handled in Java vs C." I am aware of the difference. What I am asking is what would preclude a Java compiler from transforming int `a[10][10]` into `int a[100]` and then emit `a[23]` in lieu of `a[2][3]` behind the scenes. I mean the bycode equivalent to that.

Comment: @edTarik The answer is already given in my previous comment, just think you idea *through* - and by through I mean answer the questions: how would you implement slice references? How would you *properly* implement array bounds checking? How would you implement the array.length attribute? What would the *type* of such an array be? You're just thinking about how you could put the stuff in memory without any concern about all the other constraints the language already imposes on how things behave; consequently you dont (want to?) *see* why it requires language changes.

Comment: Array bound checking is done in a language such as C by specifying a flag at compile time. Are you trying to convince me that we cannot come up with a 2D, 3D or n D object that would implement all of that and have the compiler take care of hiding the details? Java does similar stuff when dealing with enumerables and strings. I still do not see a convincing argument about the necessity to have a change in the JVM to support multidimensional arrays instead of jagged arrays.

Comment: @edTarik Now you're just ranting. And you are confusing *compiler options* with *language definition* - thats a major problem when you want to discuss language vs implementation changes. You see no convincing arguments, my reply to that is simply you *didn't* go trough the trouble to answer a *single* of the questions I posed on how you would implement it; the semantics are tightly defined at many layers in the JLS. The compiler cannot hide whats been defined to be accessible in the programming model of the language.

Comment: @edTarik Sigh... do you really believe you are *smarter* than all those guys working on the VM? If it were that easy it would be there already!

Comment: Durandal's ultimate argument: I pretend to be smarter than others. I am asking for technical arguments not an IQ evaluation. And no, I do not pretend being smarter that the guys working on the VM.

Comment: By the way, my whole argumentation was centered around the idea of doing that at the compiler level, without requiring a JVM modification. It seems however that you did not find useful to read it. Maybe are you too smart for that...

Comment: @edTarik Thats brilliant: *"around the idea of doing that at the compiler level, without requiring a JVM modification"*. Before spouting such a statement maybe you should get a grasp whats possible for the compiler in question and whats not. Then you would understand just how *embarrassing* your statement is as a reply.

Comment: Unlike you, I do not pretend to know it all and my ego will not prevent me from backing off in view of clear arguments. What I have seen so far are implicit claims that I am too ignorant or do not have a sufficient IQ to understand ideas emanating from geniuses such as you I presume. What I have seen so far are empty claims with no real substance.

Comment: @edTarik I see this discussion is pointless, probably it was pointless after comment #8. While you see "empty claims" from my side, you fail to see that the same can be said for your arguments - you haven made any proposal how it *can* work. The tiny difference lies in that I already pointed out the problem areas in comment #8. Then again you argue "on the compiler level it will be possible"; which is funny because javac produces bytecode, for which is well defined which operations are possible and also that it has *no control* over actual memory layout.

Comment: @edTarik And while you say your ego doesn't prevent you from backing off, your ego prevented you so far from at least checking out the pointers given. You are stuck in a loop where you only see how you want to transform the array, without any concern that there is much more to consider. Again see comment #8, its not enough to just manage N indices into N dimensions. The type system must also work unchanged, which presents a very hard problem. The next hard problem is that jaggedness is a key feature that has to be still possible. And predicting *if* an array will be made jagged is hard.

Comment: I did not mean to have an array that does both jagged and otherwise. I meant to have an multiarray class with Java language support. I will have a look at your pointer though.

Comment: @edTarik With the assumption that the language is to be left unchanged, the monolithic multidim array can't simply replace the jagged array because jaggedness is a visible, advertised and used feature of the language. From there follows both variants need to *coexist*, and that coexistance needs to be transparently hidden away; monolithic when *possible*, jagged when *needed*. If they are both the *same* type internally or not is an implementation choice - but to the program they need to appear to be the same with identical semantics. Thats already a much harder problem than it might seem.

Comment: @edTarik ... and by hard I mean hard as in solving the *halting problem* for the general case. To safely make an array monolithic the compiler (or VM or whatever) would need to predict the entire code path the array may pass through during its life cycle to check if jaggedness is *ever* required.

Comment: As I said, I did not mean to have a hybrid array. The current jagged array representation stays as is and another syntax is provided for the multi dim array. I am just repeating this again hoping you will read it. I am aware of the casi impossibility to do otherwise, and never meant that in the first place.

Comment: @edTarik "Another syntax" is a language change by common definition; ok you did leave that point ambigous. But it only reduces the number of traps. If this would to be implemented solely by the java compiler one problem still is that the compiler cannot create new array types for already existing types, there is only one bytecode for creating an array (newarray) taking only two arguments (component type and length); and the compiler cannot introduce new primitive types. Then there is the problem of native methods (System.arraycopy comes to mind) the compiler has no control over either.

Comment: Compiler modification already previously mentioned implies language change. Nothing surprising here. A non jagged array class can be defined, and the details hidden away using syntactic sugar. AFAIK something similar has already been done for the String class which seems like a primitive type but is not in fact. All of this already mentioned in this thread. Let me be explicit: Yes we are talking about language change but no JVM change unless we pursue improved performance and array operations the like of numpy for which a JSR existed at some point but was dropped.

Comment: @edTarik Agreed, you can hide almost anything behind a wrapper class; but even in the case of String there is some VM involvement (intern). Likewise there would be a need to modify the VM (at least marginally) for newarraytype.getClass().isArray(); unless you define the new type *isn't* an array type in that sense. So in that sense, yes you are right, it is possible to do this with *just* the java compiler. Although I would argue adding a level of indirection to get rid of indirection defeats the purpose and reporting misleading class properties is questionable at best.